# Has the pronunciation of 'Mjolnir' ever been given in the comics?

Tags: marvel, comics, thor-marvel

What the question title asks. Has anyone ever given the pronunciation of Thor's hammer, *Mjolnir*, in any of the comics? I'm not looking for **attempts** to pronounce, but rather someone who knows how to say the name explaining how to properly say it.

I'd prefer examples from before the first time it was said in a TV or movie appearance, but if there are none, then from anything after is fine.

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/rPIU5bp.jpg - Not the most helpful though.

Comment: I assume you're looking for an in-universe example, as opposed to (say) a letters page or Bullpen Bulletins reference?

Comment: I would look up danish, or Swedish,  or nowegian pronunciation rules? It is Scandinavian Ay

Comment: @RDFozz A character in the comics giving the pronunciation to another character in the comics, yeah

Comment: Honestly, it's hard to work pronunciation into a story, as the characters are talking and would (in-universe) hear the word pronounced. The only cases I can think of are Sub-Mariner (after reading a number of people calling him the "Submareener", and realizing that the phonetic spelling was meant to indicate the mispronunciation) (Probably from *MARVEL TEAM-UP* 14), and a case where the Hulk pronounced Magneto's named as "Mag-Neat-O" (this one's from *DEFENDERS* (from the 1970s) 15 or 16), which seemed to indicate a hesitation between the syllables. I'd been mispronouncing both names....

Comment: It's next to impossible to say, how it's pronounced correctly, only that Mjolnir is WRONG.. Norse mythology is split between Norway, Denmark, Iceland and Sweden. In Swedish and Icelandic, it's called Mjöllnir and in Danish and Norwegian, it's called Mjølner... Without phonetics, which few reads and even fewer writes, it makes no sense to debate how to pronounce it correctly in writing.. Just know, Hollywood version is not even close.. Also, Marvel Thor is lacking "Iarngreiper" (his glove), so he shouldn't even be able to catch it..

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mj%C3%B6lnir

Answer (score 2):

Thor gives us the pronunciation and correct spelling in [Ultimate Power #4](https://www.marvel.com/comics/issue/6128/ultimate_power_2006_4)

[image]

As to how it's *supposed* to be pronounced, Stan Lee was kind enough to give us his version:

> 'Moln-yeer'

Comment: Thor is actually saying "Mjlonir", the ᛟ and ᛚ runes have been swapped around. Rookie mistake for a Norse god

Comment: @fez - It's almost as if the comic-book artists weren't expecting the average reader to check. That being said, I *personally* think that artists and filmmakers do this sort of thing on purpose to get people talking about their products.